# How to deal with a comment that promotes to reopen a question?

Tags: discussion, comments, vote-to-reopen

I see from time to time comments that try to influence votes in one way or another.

Reviewing reopen votes, I feel surprised by a comment on the post [I bought a domain and I want to apply it on my Amazon Ec2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029877/i-bought-a-domain-and-i-want-to-apply-it-on-my-amazon-ec2-instance). It says:

> if you feel that this is a valid question and should be reopened (as
>   do i) and you have 3000+ points, please vote above to REOPEN. if you
>   dont have the necessary points, flag question for moderator attention.
>   tks

I think this question is off-topic and will take better place in SuperUser or ServerFault, thus I vote not to reopen.

Each reviewer is entitled to their own votes, but is it a good practice to ask people to a flag question for moderator attention?

My personal feeling is to flag the comment for moderator attention. What is your feeling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the comment explained *why* the question merited reopening, rather than just *that* it merited reopening, it could be useful.  As it is, it's adding nothing.  It's not a helpful comment; it's just noise.  I guess you could flag it on those grounds, if you really wanted to, although I wouldn't consider it particularly important to do so.

The statement that other people should be flagging it for moderator attention is completely incorrect advice.  There's essentially no situation where it's ever appropriate to comment telling people to flag a post (outside of meta).  If you feel the post merits moderator attention then you flagging it accomplishes that; there's no need for additional flags.  On top of that, that you feel a post should be reopened isn't reason to flag for a mod; you should just vote to reopen; that's the appropriate course of action in such a situation.

Answer (score 5):

I'd just leave it alone. From the question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5029877/timeline), you can see it has been reviewed for reopening *five* times since the comment was posted, with an anonymous 'Leave Closed' as the result. The community is doing a perfect job here.

> But is it a good practice to ask people to a flag question for moderator attention?

No, definitely not. Unless there is a flagrant violation of the site rules, ♦ moderators shouldn't be involved.